# Portfolio risk budgeting using CVaR function from PerformanceAnalytics in R

Tags: programming, portfolio-management, risk-management

I have been looking at `CVaR` function in the `PerformanceAnalytics` package as an option to use in portfolio optimization. However, I cannot figure out the reason behind discrepancy that the function is giving for my test portfolio.

Here is a reproducable example:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

set.seed(1234)
a = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 0.02)
b = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 0, sd = 0.03)

wght = c(0.4, 0.6)  ## assign weights

dt = cbind(a, b)

startDate = as.Date("2016-01-01") 
h = seq(1:10)
myDates = startDate + h

dt = as.data.frame(dt)  ## dataframe of single assets
rownames(dt) = myDates

tmp = sweep(dt, 2, wght, `*`)

P = as.data.frame(rowSums(tmp))  ## resultant portfolio
colnames(P) = "Portfolio"
```

My issue arises here:

```
MES1 = ES(dt, p = 0.95, method = "modified", portfolio_method = "component",
       weights = wght)
MES1$MES[1]
MES2 = ES(P, p = 0.95, method = "modified", portfolio_method = "component",
      weights = 1)
MES2$MES[1]
```

I get the same results of `CVaR` for the portfolio in both cases. However, when I do not mention `portfolio_method = "component"` and `weights = 1` should I not get the same result?

```
ES(P, p = 0.95, method = "modified")
```

Here the function returns completely different result. I am currently inspecting the code on the authors' [page](https://github.com/cran/PerformanceAnalytics/blob/4c10886157a80dff2a25b28bb2ee83c1ab857639/R/ES.R), but would also like to know the views of those who went through this.

Some background information regarding the methodology and implementation can be found [here](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/387170/1/jor_boudt_journalofrisk.pdf) and [here](https://quantstrattrader.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/an-introoduction-to-portfolio-component-value-at-risk/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a bit of a problem with the code when the option `portfolio_method` = "single" is used.   In the code below, your three calculations with `ES` are repeated using `method`="gaussian" and then compared with expected shortfall calcuated directly from the expression using mu and sigma.  I've done the direct calculation with `dt` using the `cov()` function and with `P` using the `sd()` function.    The resuls of all calcuations should be identical.  Similar to your case, all agree except the `ES(P, portfolio_method = "single")` calculation.

Looking into the `ES` code, the different portfolio_method options use different code to calculate sigma and higher moments.  In particular, for gaussian calculations, `ES` calculates sigma using `cov()` for `portfolio_method = "component"` and a general higher moment calculation function `centeredmoment()` for `portfolio_method = "single".`  The problem is that for `n` = number of rows in the return vector, `cov()` and `sd()` normalize the moment calculations using `1/(n-1)` while the calculations using `centeredmoment()` use `1/n`.    I've demonstrated this in the code below where the calculation for `ES_P_modied_sigma` rescales sigma to use the `1/n` normalization and gets the same result as `ES(P, portfolio_method ="single")` for the Gausian distributions.

The discrepancy is more apparent in your test calculation since you're using a small number of rows.    As the number of rows increases, the descrepancy becomes much smaller.  Nevertheless, it's something that should be corrected.

```
#
#  repeat ES calculations using Gaussian distributions
#  
  MES1g = ES(dt, p = 0.95, method = "gaussian", portfolio_method = "component",
            weights = wght)
  MES2g = ES(P, p = 0.95, method = "gaussian", portfolio_method = "component",
            weights = 1)
  MES3g <- ES(P, p = 0.95, method = "gaussian")
#
#  calculate Gaussian shortfalls directly using dt and wght and then P 
#
  prob <- .05
  mean_dt <-  apply(dt,2,mean)%*%wght
  sigma_dt <-  sqrt(t(wght)%*%cov(dt)%*%wght)
  ES_dt <- -mean_dt + dnorm(qnorm(prob))*sigma_dt/prob

  mean_P <- mean(P[,1])
  sigma_P <- sd(P[,1])
  ES_P <- -mean_P + dnorm(qnorm(prob))*sigma_P/prob 
#
# redo calculation with P using sigma scaled by sqrt((nrow(P) - 1)/nrow(P))
#
  ES_P_modied_sigma <- -mean_P + dnorm(qnorm(prob))*sigma_P/prob*(sqrt((nrow(P)-1)/nrow(P))) 
#
# compare all results
# note that result ES_P_modified_sigma reproduces MES3g showing problem with normalization for sigma
# 
  c(MES1g$ES, MES2g$ES, MES3g)
  c(ES_dt, ES_P, ES_P_modied_sigma)
```

Comment: Thank you WaltS. I cannot seem to find the calculation function `centeredmoment()` and its code in the repo, can you please give me a link?

Comment: With PerformanceAnalytics loaded into your R session, type centeredmoment with no trailing parentheses at the command line.  The code for the function should appear.  centeredmoment is also described in the help docs for PerformananceAnalytics.